# Trigger update for Dynamo DB items

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm looking for a solution to trigger update event for Dynamo DB records without actual updates to the records, but I can't find if there is a built-in solution for this.

I can of course retrieve items one-by-one and update something on them (like `updated_at` field), but I don't think this is an effective solution.

The purpose of all of this is to trigger update stream for all these records for data migration purposes via lambda.

Comment: I wouldn't try to trick the system like this. If you know the eventual target for the DynamoDB streams e.g. a specific Lambda function then just invoke that directly by reading the relevant items, and pass them to the Lambda. Ideally, I would use a different handler function in the same Lambda, or provide contextual information, to distinguish a real DDB stream update vs your fake update.

Comment: @jarmod yep, I'm thinking about something similar as a workaround

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by `scan`ning of the table item and passing item directly into lambda.